# java compute pi to 6 significant figurs

Tags: java, loops, pi

I'm having trouble with this program, we are supposed to compute pi to six significant figures, WITHOUT ROUNDING and WITHOUT using math library constant, the program should also show the number of iterations it took to reach 6 sig fig accuracy as well as the math constant in the output, so far I'm just trying to get my head around computing pi, I'm completely lost on how to get six 6 figs with or without rounding, not to mention how to iterate how many iterations it took to reach 6 sig figs pls help.

"Write an algorithm and program to compute π, using the formula described in the text `PI/4 =1-(1/3)+(1/5)-(1/7)+(1/9)....`" Output will include your computed value for π, the math library constant expected value for π and the number of iterations it took to reach six-significant digit accuracy. The number of iterations could exceed 250,000. Make your output clean and easy to read for comparing results.

This is the code I have so far to compute pi but even this I'm not sure is right.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {      
    Double pi=1.0;
    int s=1;
    for (double j=3.0; j<100.0; j=j+2)
    {
        if (s % 2 == 0)
            pi = pi + (1/j);
        else
            pi = pi - (1/j);
        s = s + 1;
    }
    System.out.println(4*pi);
```

Comment: so what is going wrong with your code?

Comment: i thought the " j<" would help me to get to significant figures for instance "j<6" would get me pi to 6 significant figures but when i put in 6 i get 3.466666666666667, when i put in 1 and or 2 i get 4.0 so it seems like im getting close to computing pi but i =m not sure how to get it to 6 significant figures without rounding

Comment: The error of approximation in an alternating series like yours is bounded by the magnitude of the next term. So you want to take it pretty far out to get your estimate to be right to like 1/10001 or maybe a fourth of that.

Comment: Or the other technique is just to wait until two successive approximations you get are the same to 6 sig figs (then it will have converged as much as you need).

Comment: no matter how far out i take it it wont go to 6 sig figs and i need to comput pi to 6 sig figs without rounding

Comment: What estimate does it give you if you change j<100.0 to j<10003.0, say?

Comment: 3.1417926135957908 @JeremyKahan

Comment: OK. So we are heading the right direction.Let us think it through. We have 4-4/3+4/5-4/7... (I am not suggesting you calculate it this way, just thinking about sig figs. We want an estimate good to 6 sig figs (3.14159 in hindsight), so our error needs to under .000005. 1/(j+2) must be less than .000005. Solve that and make it your j< value.

Comment: Above should be 4/(j+2)<.000005. Or 4/(j+2)<5/1000000. Take reciprocals and (j+2)/4>200000, j+2>800000, and j>799998. Set your upper bound to j<799998.0 (or a little higher to be safe), and you should be golden.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

consider

```
        String piStr = "3.14159";
        Double pi=1.0;
        int s=1;
        double j=3.0; 
        String lcl = "";
        String upToNCharacters = "";
        while (true)
        {
            if (s % 2 == 0)
                pi = pi + (1/j);
            else
                pi = pi - (1/j);

            s = s + 1;
            j=j+2;
            
            lcl = "" + 4 * pi;
            upToNCharacters = lcl.substring(0, Math.min(lcl.length(), 7));
            if (upToNCharacters.equals(piStr)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(upToNCharacters);
        System.out.println("after " + s);
```

**output**

> 3.14159
>
> after 136121

Comment: i dont know what the "lcl" or "upTONCharacters" is doing plus arent you using a math constant?

Comment: I am pretty sure that is 7 significant figures. But also, if you already knew pi, then why estimate it? I believe the exercise wants you either to estimate the error up front or test for convergence on the fly, not check against a number we pretend we do not know.

Comment: @JeremyKahan I agree it is not a real world solution, but it does fit within the bounds of the above requirements.

Comment: @JeremyKahan Of course if you come up with a better solution, please post it an I will delete mine and upvote yours.

Comment: @ScaryWombat isnt a math constant used in that program?

Comment: No, the Math constant is not used https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#PI

Comment: Mine is not better, but I think yours could be adapted something like this. Add a string prevUpToNCharacters="-1"; Then your             if (upToNCharacters.equals(piStr)) {
                break; }becomes             if (upToNCharacters.equals(prevUpToNCharacters)) 
                break; else prevUpToNCharacters=upToNCharacters;

Comment: @ScaryWombat the programs seems to work and should fit the requirements, im trying to get my head around it, do you mind explaining what "j=j+2;

            lcl = "" + 4 * pi;
            upToNCharacters = lcl.substring(0, Math.min(lcl.length(), 7));
            if (upToNCharacters.equals(piStr)) {
                break;"' this part is doing? as well as why pi is made out to be a string on the first line of code?

Comment: and im not sure what this means in the programs specifications, these were part of our instructions "You may NOT use the math library constant in your computation - directly or indirectly. Use the delta of your running computation to determine when to stop.

Comment: What @ScaryWombat is doing is converting the approximation to a string (sequence of characters), copying them, and seeing if they match PI as a string to enough characters (and when they do, break gets out of the loop). Technically Math.PI was not called. But that part about the DELTA is saying you know when to stop when adding the next term did not make a significant change in the approximation. If you look up at my preceding comment, I sketch how ScaryWombat's approach could be adapted to meet this requirement about the DELTA.

Answer (score 1):

So there is presumably a way to make an a priori estimate of error using the alternating series theorem. But suppose you do not know the theorem or trust your math (if you do, just change 100.0 above to the right number. 800000.0 as estimated above would work, just barely). Here is something a little safer, perhaps, though it might be better to check the goodness of the estimate only every 1000 times through the loop, not each time?

```
Double pi=1.0; Boolean closeEnough=false;
    int s=1;
    for (double j=3.0; (!closeEnough); j=j+2)
    {
        if (s % 2 == 0)
            pi = pi + (1/j);
        else
            pi = pi - (1/j);
        if (Math.abs(4/(j+2))<0.000005)
            closeEnough=true;

        s = s + 1;
    }
```

Comment: apparently we are supposed to make the program as efficient as possible? "Efficiency should always be considered. No rounding is required or allowed. Choose the most appropriate loop/decision structures and variable types.  @jeremyKahan

Comment: @jeremyKahan - I have upvoted your answer.  Whereas my answer does meet the requirements, IMO it does not meet the spirit of the assignment.  Yours works well without needing to use any approximation of PI.

Comment: So I was working with your method. I did not round, as far as I can tell, and I did check the delta (since the change in approximation is the next added term). There are definitely some ways to be a bit more efficient. j could be an integer type (probably int works; long for sure does). Also I am doing 2 divisions per cycle through the loop, but if you simplified my inequality by dividing both sides by 4, you could get away with just one. Good luck in the course.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should encapsulate your calculation in a class:

```
public class PI {
    private double estimate = 1.0;
    private int iteration = 0;

    public double getEstimate() {
        return 4 * estimate;
    }

    public void iterate() {
        double ratio = 1.0 / (iteration * 2 + 3);
        if (iteration % 2 == 0)
            estimate -= ratio;
        else
            estimate += ratio;
        iteration++;
    } 
}
```

Then the loop becomes pretty trivial:

```
PI pi = new PI();
while (Math.round(pi.getEstimate() * 1e5) != Math.round(Math.PI * 1e5))
    pi.iterate();
```

For me this took 130,657 iterations

Comment: If invoking Math.PI is not actually against the directions, it is for sure against the spirit. You do not get to know PI when you are checking your estimate of PI. I think you could strengthen this by seeing if 2 consecutive estimates are the same when rounded to 5 decimal places.